# Is transaction enough to handle simultaneous thousands or miliions of requests in codeigniter 3.x based application?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Is implenting transaction in codeigniter enought to handle simultaneous thousands or even millions of requests at the same time? like e.g in my model like this

transaction begin
insert data in table one. 
insert data in table two
commit
esle if failed
rollback

Comment: please be more specific

Comment: thousands of millions of inserts to db at the same time. an api request if thats specific enough for you

Comment: guess it would depend on how powerful your server is - doubtful shared hosting would be able to handle millions of db inserts at once let alone requests. i wouldn't really classify this as a potential CI issue or a transaction issue. in all likelihood it would just take requests longer to process if your server isn't up to the task. transactions are indeed a good way to ensure that data that is tightly coupled is entered properly in a multi table scheme. but I certainty don't think this is something answerable without bringing opinions or guesses into the mix.